# systemd: service dependency "If A is not running, B should not run"?

Tags: linux, systemd

*(systemd version 229, fwiw)*

I have a primary service A, and a secondary service B. The primary A can run by itself. But service B cannot run correctly by itself: it needs A to be running (technically B can run, but this is what I want systemd to prevent). My goal: **If A is not running, B should not run.** Given that A and B are running, when A stops or dies/crashes, then B should be stopped.

How do I achieve this?

I get close by adding [Unit] items to b.service, using

```
Requisite=A.service
After=A.service
```

The result of the above is that

```
1) B won't start unless A is running (good).
2) B is stopped when A is stopped (good).
3) However, if I kill A, service B continues to run (bad).
```

How can I fix this last behavior #3? I tried using BindsTo instead of Requisite, like this in B's service file:

```
BindsTo=A.service
After=A.service
```

and I get:

```
1) If A is not running and I start B, then A is also started
    (I want an error, I don't want A started)
2) B is stopped when A is stopped (good).
3) B is stopped when A is killed (good)
```

So now #3 is good but #1 is not the desired behaviour.
Neither PartOf nor BindsTo seems to do the trick, but perhaps I don't have the right incantation of combinations of options? Its not clear to me from the man pages what options can be combined.

With BindsTo, I also tried failing B's start using ExecStartPre, but of course this didn't work because the start of B had already determined that it needed A to run (and started it), before it fired up B.

Is there some way to get a behaviour inbetween Requisite and BindsTo? The 1-2-3 I've listed above?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Have you had any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking for a more elegant solution.
There is an open systemd ticket for Request for enhancement here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5966

Currently my workaround is as follow:
B.service

```
Requisite=A.service
After=A.service
```

A.service

```
OnFailure=Stop-B.service
```

Stop-B.service

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=0
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl stop B.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation to solve. The approach I came up with involve creating a target unit as *barrier* between the two services.

a.service:

```
[Unit]
Wants=a.target
```

a.target:

```
[Unit]
Requisite=a.service
After=a.service
PartOf=a.service
RefuseManualStart=true
RefuseManualStop=true
```

b.service:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=a.target
After=a.target
```

This setup produces the behavior the OP desires, since a.target is always active with a.service (PartOf stops a.target when a.service is stopped, RefuseManual* avoid systemctl start/stop commands on a.target), and b.service cannot start a.service via a.target.

Comment: This didn't do exactly what I wanted, because the PartOf=a.service line in a.target does not cause a.target (and therefor b.service) to be stopped if a.service goes inactive (as opposed to being explicitly stopped).  And using BindsTo=a.service instead of PartOf=a.service doesn't work because it overrides the Requisite=a.service line and starts a.service when b.service is started.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a similar approach to Chris's, but without needing to create a separate service for stopping B:

**B.service**:

```
[Unit]
Requisite=A.service
After=A.service
```

**A.service**:

```
[Service]
ExecStopPost=/bin/systemctl stop B.service
```

The `Requisite` line in B.service ensures that B.service cannot be started if A.service is not already running, while the `ExecStopPost` line in A.service ensures that B.service gets stopped when A.service is stopped or goes inactive.